# Find duplicates in three columns and add plus 1 to results in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to identify duplicate values in three columns and sum +1 in the results of another column.

```
# This is my data frame,
# I want to identify duplication in column1, column2 and column3
d = {
'Column1': ['1', '1', '2','3'],
'column2': [101, 101, 234, 203],
'column3': ['c', 'c', 'd','c'],
'columnx': ['0.1', '0.2', '0.1','0.2']}

     Column1  column2 column3 columnx
0       1      101       c      0.1
1       1      101       c      0.2
2       2      234       d      0.1
3       3      203       c      0.2
```

Desired result

```
     Column1  column2 column3 columnx
0       1      101       c      1.1
1       1      101       c      1.2
2       2      234       d      0.1
3       3      203       c      0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find all duplicated rows with `DataFrame.duplicated(keep=False)` then conditionally assign the summation result

```py
m = df.duplicated(['Column1', 'column2', 'column3'], keep=False)
df.loc[m, 'columnx'] = df['columnx'].add(1)
```

```
print(df)

   Column1  column2 column3  columnx
0        1      101       c      1.1
1        1      101       c      1.2
2        2      234       d      0.1
3        3      203       c      0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by converting columnx to numeric:

```
df['columnx'] = pd.to_numeric(df['columnx'], errors='coerce')
```

Next, call `duplicated` (returns bools) and just add it back:

```
df['columnx'] += df[['Column1', 'column2', 'column3']].duplicated(keep=False)
df
  Column1  column2 column3  columnx
0       1      101       c      1.1
1       1      101       c      1.2
2       2      234       d      0.1
3       3      203       c      0.2
```

This updates the DataFrame in-place. Alternatively, create a copy using

```
df2 = df.assign(columnx=df[['Column1', 'column2', 'column3']]
                      .duplicated(keep=False).add(df['columnx']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {
    'Column1': ['1', '1', '2', '3'],
    'column2': [101, 101, 234, 203],
    'column3': ['c', 'c', 'd', 'c'],
    'columnx': ['0.1', '0.2', '0.1', '0.2']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
duplicates = df.duplicated(subset=['Column1', 'column2', 'column3'], keep=False)
df.loc[duplicates, 'columnx'] = (df.loc[duplicates, 'columnx'].astype(float) + 1).astype(str)
```

Output :

```
  Column1  column2 column3 columnx
0       1      101       c     1.1
1       1      101       c     1.2
2       2      234       d     0.1
3       3      203       c     0.2
```